# Find another solution for second order homogenous linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find another solution for equation
$$
y'' + \frac{y'}{x} - \frac{y}{4x^2} = 0,\ x\in\ (0, \infty)
$$
when one solution is $y_1(x) = \sqrt x$.

Another linearly independent solution for equations in the format $y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$ should be
$$
y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int\frac{e^{-\int p(x)dx}}{y_1(x)^2}dx = \dots = -\frac{1}{\sqrt x},
$$
but now calculating Wronskian determinant gives
$$
W = y_1y_2'-y_2y_1' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}=0.
$$
So now universal solution isn't $y_h=C_1y_1+C_2y_2$. Is that a wrong approach for finding another solution for this differential equation?

Comment: Are you sure you did the wronskian properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Wronskian is off.

$$y_1 = \sqrt{x}$$
$$y'_1 = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
$$y_2 = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$y'_2 = \frac{1}{2 x \sqrt{x}}$$
$$y_1 y'_2 = \frac{1}{2x}$$
$$y'_1 y_2 = -\frac{1}{2x}$$
$$y_1 y'_2 - y'_1 y_2 = \frac{1}{2x}-(-\frac{1}{2x})=\frac{1}{x}$$

---

### Addendum

It's been suggested that the OP's solution is inaccurate. Let's try it out:
$$ y_1 = \sqrt{x}$$
$$y'_1 = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
$$y'_1 = -\frac{1}{4x\sqrt{x}}$$
$$ \frac{y_1}{4 x^2} = \frac{1}{4 x \sqrt{x}}$$
$$ \frac{y'_1}{ x} = \frac{1}{2 x \sqrt{x}}$$
$$ y''_1 = -\frac{1}{4 x \sqrt{x}}$$
my understanding is that this forms:

$$-\frac{1}{4 x \sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{2 x \sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{4 x \sqrt{x}} = (-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4})\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}=0$$

OP's proposed answer is accurate.

---

### Alternative approach

One can come upon the OP's answer using an *ansatz* that $y=Cx^m$
We then find based on the derivatives $C$ is a free parameter and $m(m-1)+m-1/4=0$ which leaves $m = \pm \frac{1}{2}$. These are the solutions found by OP

Comment: No way! Double checked all my calculations literally million times and it turns out that I can't derive $\sqrt x$. Embarrasing.

Comment: @jte it happens :) glad I could help

Comment: @Isham How come $y = \sqrt x$ is not a solution? I get $y' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$ and $y'' = -\frac{1}{4\sqrt x x}$ and placing them in to equation gives 0.

Comment: @jte : seems that taking derivatives is a cursed operation all around today :)

Comment: Seems like it. Also that alternative approach was a good point. Going to scratch that to my notebook as well.

Comment: Once you know the answer a good ansatz makes life easier

Comment: The derivative of $-x^{-1/2}$ is $\frac12x^{-3/2}$, you have the coefficient wrong.

Comment: Blarg thanks for the help